# Как исправить ошибку в коде swift

Tags: swift

Изучаю swift. Написал небольшой код, но выдает ошибку Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Float'.
Вот код:
'''

```
import UIKit

print("Введите рост в сантиметрах: ")
let height = readLine()
print("Введите вес в килограммах: ")
let weight = readLine()
func squareBody (heightBody: Float, weightBody: Float) -> Float {
    let squareBodyMath = 0.0167 * pow(heightBody, 0.5) * pow(weightBody, 0.5)
    return squareBodyMath
}
var resultSquareBody = squareBody(heightBody: height!, weightBody: weight!)
let formatResultSquareBody = String(format: "%.2f", resultSquareBody)
print("Индекс массы тела: ", formatResultSquareBody)
```

'''
Как исправить ошибку. Пробовал в resultSquareBody добавить Float(height!) - не помогает.
Сделал вот так:
'''

```
import UIKit

print("Введите рост в сантиметрах: ")
let height = Float(readLine()!)!
print("Введите вес в килограммах: ")
let weight = Float(readLine()!)!
func squareBody(heightBody: Float, weightBody: Float) -> Float {
    let squareBodyMath = 0.0167 * pow(heightBody, 0.5) * pow(weightBody, 0.5)
    return squareBodyMath
}
var resultSquareBody = squareBody(heightBody: height, weightBody: weight)
let formatResultSquareBody = String(format: "%.2f", resultSquareBody)
print("Индекс массы тела: ", formatResultSquareBody)
```

'''
Выдает ошибку Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value Playground execution failed.
В интернете толком ответа не могу найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените в первой части кода на:

```
var resultSquareBody = squareBody(heightBody: Float(height ?? "") ?? 0, weightBody: Float(weight ?? "") ?? 0)
```

height и weight у вас имеют тип String?, т.е. опциональный String, потому что введения значения может не быть. Вам нужно вначале преобразовать String? в  String через nil coalescing ?? "", затем получившийся Float? во Float через ?? 0.

Comment: Ошибку перестал выдавать, но почему-то сразу вычисляет результат и он равен 0.0. Не дает ввести данные в консоль

Comment: А как вы запускаете код? Попробуйте, например, сделать приложение для консоли, Command Line Tool для macOS, и запускайте оттуда.

Comment: Запускаю в Xcode. Через playground для ios

Comment: В playground нельзя ввести данные. Сделайте, как я написал в комментарии выше.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо.